# Dynamic classes not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

The class doesn't change, however the reactive ref is changed.
This is the code

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 100) {
      Show.value = true
    } else {
      Show.value = false
    }
    console.log(window.scrollY, Show.value)
  })
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll')
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="nav" :class="{'nav_black': Show }">
</div>
```

I don't know where the problem is to solve

Comment: There's no reason the code should exist inside a watchEffect, but either way there's nothing functionally wrong with the code.  Inspect the div class names in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-haslett-49jmgr?file=/src/App.vue) while scrolling to see what I mean. You need to post enough code to reproduce the problem.